# Svelte - Undesired: on:mouseXXX event in parent div is triggered by child div

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I have a parent div which when clicked, initializes a function. Inside this parent div, i have selectable and draggable divs which in an intuitive sense are suppose to "lay above the parent div" or "lay inside the drawing board". These child divs also have functions initialized when these divs are clicked.

My problem is that mouseclicks made on these child divs, triggers mouseclicks on the parent div. The on:mouseclick action defined in the parent div shall only be initialized when clicking the parent div, and not when clicking the child div.

Screenshot taken from inspection. Here the div with the class "board" is the parent div, containing a on:mouseclick, which should not be triggered when clicking on the child divs contained in the parent div.
[image: Screenshot taken from inspection.]

A codesnippet. Here, when ObjectSelection and ObjectOnBoard are clicked, the shown on:mouseup action is triggered, which is undesirable.

```
<div class='board' on:mouseup={$selected != null ? createObject : null}>

    <ObjectSelection/>
    
    {#each $editor.objects as object}
        <ObjectOnBoard bind:x={object.geometry.x} bind:y={object.geometry.y}/>
    {/each}

</div>
```

Comment: Please do not screenshot code. You can copy element markup from dev tools via the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal behavior for events to bubble up the hierarchy. You can either...

- Stop the event on the child level by handling it there and calling `stopPropagation`/use the [event modifier](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-on-eventname) with the same name for that.
- Filter your logic at the parent by comparing the `event.target` with `event.currentTarget`, if they are the same, the event occurred at the parent's level. As noted in the comments, the event modifier `self` also performs this function.

Also, using a click event on regular `div` elements is not accessible. If something is clickable it usually should be a `button` or an `a` element, depending on its function. Styling can be adjusted to fit the context.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! stopPropagation did not work as intended, but applying self ( on:mouseup|self={...} ) made the code work as intended! Now, the function createObject (disregard the if-statement) is initialized only when actually pressing the actual div, and not initialized when pressing the child divs.
Also i'll take a look at my elements, i'm new to html and i thought div was a more general purpose element, i'll look it up!

Comment: `div` is the most general-purpose block element of them all, which is exactly why it should not be used when the intended function is more specialized. In particular for interactive elements it is important to choose the correct one, otherwise they cannot be used with the keyboard and screen readers will lack important context.

Comment: I added the note on the `self` modifier to the answer, which is a bit more concise than doing the check manually.